# Forest Plot Design questions

Tags: r, plot, r-forestplot

I am creating a forest plot with the forestplot() function.

The forest plot looks like this:
[Forest Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4AZb.png)

```
    ## Labels defining subgroups are a little indented!
subgps <- c(4,5,8,9,12,13,16,17,20,21,24,25,28,29,32,33)
data$Variable[subgps] <- paste("  ",data$Variable[subgps]) 
align = c("l", "l", "l", "l", "l", "l", "l", "l", "l", "l", "l")

library(forestplot)
png(file.path(workdir,"Figures\\Forestplot3.png"),width=1280, height=1000)
forestplot(labeltext=tabletext, graph.pos=3, 
           mean=c(NA,NA,data$Point.Estimate), 
           lower=c(NA,NA,data$Low), upper=c(NA,NA,data$High),
           title="Hazard Ratio",
           xlab="<---favors no ß-blockers---  ---favors ß-blockers--->", xlab.position="left",
           hrzl_lines=list("3" = gpar(lwd=1, col="#99999922"), 
                           "5" = gpar(lwd=60, lineend="butt", columns=c(2:6), col="#99999922"),
                           "14" = gpar(lwd=85, lineend="butt", columns=c(2:6), col="#99999922"),
                           "23" = gpar(lwd=60, lineend="butt", columns=c(2:6), col="#99999922"),
                           "31" = gpar(lwd=60, lineend="butt", columns=c(2:6), col="#99999922"),
                           "39" = gpar(lwd=60, lineend="butt", columns=c(2:6), col="#99999922"),
                           "47" = gpar(lwd=60, lineend="butt", columns=c(2:6), col="#99999922"),
                           "54" = gpar(lwd=27, lineend="butt", columns=c(2:6), col="#99999922")),
           txt_gp=fpTxtGp(label=gpar(cex=1.25),
                          ticks=gpar(cex=1.1),
                          xlab=gpar(cex = 1.2),
                          title=gpar(cex = 1.2)),
           col=fpColors(box="blue", lines="black", zero = "gray50"),
           zero=1, cex=0.9, lineheight = "auto", boxsize=0.5, colgap=unit(6,"mm"),
           lwd.ci=2, ci.vertices=TRUE, ci.vertices.height = 0.4)
x = .353
y0 = .08
y1 = .91
grid.lines(c(x, x), c(y0, y1), default.units = "npc",
           gp = gpar(lwd = 1.7, col="#880000"))

dev.off()
```

I have two design problems:

1. In the upper pink bubble you can see that there is a problem with the text alignment. How can I change this?
2. In the lower pink bubble there is a problem with the grey background. It is defined by ""54" = gpar(lwd=27, lineend="butt", columns=c(2:6), col="#99999922")),", but if I choose line 53 or line 54 it does not work. So the grey background does not fit to the text.

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: This is NOT a forest plot. See the accepted use of that term at the Wikipedia page or in the tutorial by the package author. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/vignettes/forestplot.html

Answer (score 1):

For alignment you should be able to use `align` in the arguments. For the latter it is most likely just a case of your graph being too large, try just increasing the height to 1200 and see if that solves your issue. Your example was lacking the  `labeltext` and thus it is a little hard to test if this fixes your issues.

Comment: Thank you @Max. Unfortunately see your answer before.

I already used the align argument, but it doesnt work. I edited it above at the beginning. 

Can you help?

Comment: @MaxGordon There are several instances of statistically naive users of your `forestplot` package using it to produce graphical displays of hazard or odds ratios for multiple confounders in a single study. Your vignette correctly describes the use of the term forest plot to describe graphical presentations of outcomes from multiple studies, but it seems the flexibility of plotting is allowing people to think that because they used the `forestplot` function that they have produced a "forest plot". Ideally this would be made clear in the help page and perhaps with a message on loading the package

Comment: @IRTFM - yes, just because it compiles it doesn't have to be correct. I don't think that a warning is that helpful - after all cookie-warnings and other warnings that are being thrown at us I think most of us have become immune to them (i.e. simply ignore them). Improving the docs is though always a good thing, please consider submitting a PR on GitHub and I'll gladly have a look at it